# Menu and Sub Menu Scripting On Linux

Tags: linux, bash, loops, menu

There is 2 things i'm not sure about which i have been trying to do for a while and i'm sorry for sounding stupid, but i'm not sure where to integrate the code so that when option A or B is pressed in the Sub Menus it says "Option A Selected"
I'm also not sure how to loop the Sub Headings so that when it has said "Option A/B Selected" it goes back to the sub menu screen. Until i Press the back to main menu button when it will go to the Main Menu. I'd much appreciate any help as i am new to this and struggling with this bit in particular, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of simplifying the task is to keep each menu in it's own function, Each menu loops until the user presses the exit key. In this case 'x' is used. My bash does not

```
function subopt1
{
   subopt1=""
   while [ "$subopt1" != "x" ]
   do
      echo Sub Menu 1 Heading
      echo Option A
      echo Option B
      echo x Back to Main Menu
      read -p "Select sub option1" subopt1
   done
 }

 function subopt2
 {
     subopt2=""
     while [ "$subopt2" != "x" ]
     do
         echo Sub Menu 2 Heading
         echo Option A
         echo Option B
         echo x Back to Main Menu
         read -p "Select sub-option2" subopt2    
     done
 }

 function mainopt
 {
    opt=""
    while [ "$opt" != "x" ]
    do
        echo Menu Heading
        echo Sub Menu 1
        echo Sub Menu 2
        read -p "Select Otion: " opt
        if [ "$opt" = "1" ]; then
             subopt1
        elif [ "$opt" = "2" ]; then
             subopt2
        elif [ "$opt" = "x" ];then
             break
        fi
   done
}

mainopt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach :

```
select x in submenu1 submenu2 exit ; do
    [[ $x == exit ]] && exit 0
    select y in optionA optionB; do
        echo "submenu $y heading"
        echo "$x selected"
        break
    done
done
```

### Example

```
1) submenu1
2) submenu2
3) exit
> 1
1) optionA
2) optionB
> 1
submenu optionA heading
submenu1 selected
>
```